# Set Single Sign on cookie

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity

I'm currently working on an ASP.NET Core 5 MVC web project, I used default created Single User Account generated template for user management. I have applied the migration and it's working fine as expected. I need to set SSO cookie so other web applications can use that and work without sign in. In .NET 5 `AccountController` is not visible. What is the best way to set SSO cookie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is "Share authentication cookies with ASP.NET Core Identity". You can see guide at reference document at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cookie-sharing?view=aspnetcore-5.0#share-authentication-cookies-with-aspnet-core-identity

You persistence it to web-browser by

```cs
services.AddDataProtection().PersistKeysToFileSystem("{PATH TO COMMON KEY RING FOLDER}").SetApplicationName("SharedCookieApp");

services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options => {options.Cookie.Name = ".AspNet.SharedCookie";});
```

Depend on your second web-application what received your cookie sharing, you can see case ***with* ASP.NET Core Identity** or ***with-out* ASP.NET Core Identity**.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cookie-sharing?view=aspnetcore-5.0#share-authentication-cookies-without-aspnet-core-identity